# iTextSharp and DataGridView

Tags: .net, pdf, datagridview, itext

Where can I find a code snippet which can convert a DataGridView to a PDF document using iTextShape or something similar?

I want to have the same table headers as in DataGridView in my PDF document.

Comment: Yes I am sorry I ment iTextSharp

Here is another solution (but code does not compile)
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/28292-Print-DataGridView-data-using-context-menu.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Exporting a DataGridView to an Excel/PDF/image file by using Reporting Services report generation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/ReportExporters_WinForms.aspx)

another way is to use crystal reports, after generating report from DataGridView you can use crystal reports to export the report to PDF.